# Force open SharePoint URL instead of download

Tags: sharepoint-online

Am using D365 Power automate to generate SharePoint history (document change history) URLs, I am able to generate like below, but the problem is it is downloading the file, instead I want to open the word document.

```
https://SITEURL/_vti_history/VERSIONID/LISTNAME/ROOTFOLDER/DOCNAME.docx
```

I have tried `web=1` in the query string, but no luck.

URL is perfect and downloading the right document, but I want to open in browser instead of download.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, when accessing the version history for a document, SharePoint is not actually storing an intact file, it stores differential pieces in a content database. When you request a specific version via URL it reconstitutes the file for you.  So downloading is really the only option since it really does not exist as a separate file (like we think about in a SharePoint library) to open in the web application.  Hope that helps.

[Where are version history documents stored?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99261c97-efda-4061-9bf9-10ec47923c36/where-are-version-history-documents-stored)